# Automating Micropython REPL Control for Pyboard Firmware Updates

Tags: python, automation, serial-port, micropython

I'm working with a Pyboard (D-Series) and need to automate the process of preparing it for firmware updates (boot mode). Specifically, I want to programmatically control the Micropython REPL (Read-Eval-Print Loop) via a Python script. This will allow me to perform tasks like triggering the bootloader and executing commands on the Pyboard in Micropython. I am using M1 Mac.
If not automated, the process would be:

```
screen /dev/*usb*
>>> import machine
>>> machine.bootloader()
```

Then pyboard would finish REPL session by itself and go into boot mode.

**What I Tried:**

1. I attempted to use the expect package in Python to control the Micropython REPL as follows:

```
screen_process = pexpect.spawn("screen /dev/*usb*")
```

or

```
fd = os.open("/dev/tty.usbmodem355B317230372", os.O_RDWR|os.O_NONBLOCK|os.O_NOCTTY)
m = pexpect.spawn(fd) 
m.send("import machine")
m.send("machine.bootloader")
```

However, it seems that the serial device requires special handling, and I encountered issues.

2. I also attempted to use the serial package in Python and followed advise of @David Grayson (Thank you):

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem355B317230372', 115200, timeout=1)
ser.write(b'\x03\x01')
ser.write(b'import machine\n')
ser.write(b'machine.bootloader()\n')
```

This seems to run fine. It does not throw any error but also does not set pyboard in the boot mode.

**What I'm Looking For:**

A guidance on how to implement this automation effectively, including sample code or best practices. If you have experience with controlling a Micropython REPL on a Pyboard D-Series or similar devices programmatically, I would greatly appreciate your insights and assistance in resolving the issues I'm facing.

I want to automate the following actions using a Python script:

1. Establish a connection to the Pyboard D-Series via USB (the Pyboard will be recognized as a serial device).
2. Start a Micropython REPL session on the Pyboard within the Python script.
3. Send commands to the Micropython REPL to trigger specific actions on the Pyboard, such as entering bootloader mode (akin to machine.bootloader()).
4. Capture and process the output or responses from the Micropython REPL within the Python script.
5. Gracefully exit the Micropython REPL session.

Any help or code examples to achieve these objectives would be highly valuable.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your second block of code where you use pySerial looks almost correct, but you are forgetting to send the parentheses (`()` ) after the word `bootloader`, so you're not actually calling that function.  So is this just a typo situation?  Also, just in case your board was running code, you might want to sent Ctrl+C and Ctrl+A characters (`\x03\x01`) first.

Comment: Thank you David! Yes, it was a typo, I have corrected. I tried adding (b'\x03\x01'), it seems like running but does not help setting pyboard in the boot mode. Would you have any suggestion what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [mpremote](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/mpremote.html#mpremote) to open a connection to the board and execute some commands inside the REPL. You could even configure a [mpremote shortcut](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/reference/mpremote.html#shortcuts) for it